# Observing streams using Cubit (BLoC library)?

Tags: flutter, bloc

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to listen to streams and emit state using `Cubit` instead of `BLoC`?

I'm using the `BLoC` library for Flutter and we use `Cubit`s for our state management. Everything is working all right so far for interactions to get data or save data but now I need to work with streams. In my case that means watching snapshots from `FirebaseFirestore`.

I tried searching the internet if there are ways to observe streams for `Cubit` rather than using `BLoC` but most of the results point me to `BLoC`. I've worked with `BLoC` in another project so I know how to use it for observing streams but I wanted to use `Cubit` instead if there is a way.

Here is an example of the code I use to observe in FireStore:

```dart
@override
  Stream<Either<Failure, List<MTalk>>> watchTalk() async* {
    const path ='path/to/talks';
    yield* firestore
        .collection(path)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (snap) => right<Failure, List<MTalk>>(
            snap.docs
                .map(
                    (documentSnapshot) => MTalk.fromFirestore(documentSnapshot))
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
        .onErrorReturnWith((e) {
      if (e is FirestoreException) {
        return left(RetrieveFailure(message: e.message));
      } else {
        return left(UnknownFailure(message: e.toString()));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When using `BLoC`, you could simply use `async*` and `yield` to return the state whenever you return data from calling `watchTalk()` because `mapEventToState()` is also a Stream that yields `State`. In the case of `Cubit`, we use `emit(MyState)` to get state in the UI and the functions aren't of type `Stream`. What I wanna know is if we can use `Cubit` to work with streams.

Comment: Yes, this is described also with examples in the documentation: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/coreconcepts?id=cubit

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone gets confused like I did it is pretty straightforward. You can call on listen on your `cubit` and emit state each time you get a value from the stream. Here's an example of my code listening for changes in network connectivity using `DataConnectionChecker`:

```dart
///Listens to the connectivity of
Future<void> listenToConnectivity() async {
  if (_internetStream != null) {
    await _internetStream.cancel();
  }
  _internetStream = repo.isConnectedToInternet().listen((result) {
    result.fold(
      (failure) => _processFailure(failure: failure),
      (isConnected) {
        if (isConnected) {
          emit(const SessionState.connected());
        } else {
          emit(const SessionState.disconnected());
        }
      },
    );
  });
}
```